# Inspecting Spring Security MethodInvocation for precise argument info

Tags: java, spring-security, reflection

Spring Security here and trying to figure out how to use a [`MethodInvocation`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/aopalliance/intercept/MethodInvocation.html) instance to get:

1. a list of all the arguments (name and type) passed to the method; and
2. each argument's corresponding value

There is the `MethodInvocation#getArguments() : Object[]` method but there is absolutely zero Spring Security documentation as to what type(s) can be returned inside the object array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an array containing all the arguments of the invoked method .The most left argument starts from the index 0 and so on.

Suppose the invoked method is :

```java
 void hello(Integer int , String str, Boolean bool);
```

and it is invoked with :

```java
  hello(1000, "world" , true);
```

Then `MethodInvocation#getArguments()` will return an array :

- at index 0 : An Integer 1000
- at index 1 : A String "world"
- at index 2 : A Boolean true

You can use `getClass()` on each of the argument object to access their type information and potentially cast it to the actual class if you want to access the specific methods of that type. Something likes:

```java
Object[] args = methodInvocation.getArguments();
args[0].getClass() // return you Integer class

if(args[0] instanceof Integer){
   ((Integer)arg[0]).intValue(); // cast it to the integer and access a specific method provided by the Integer
}
```

It returns null if the invoked method does not have any input parameters.

Comment: Thanks @Ken (+1) -- awesome answer; just curious, where did you find this info? I looked everywhere for it!

Comment: Meaning, how do you know that the instances coming back in the `arguments : Object[]` aren't `SpringArgument<Integer>`, or `SpringArgument<String>`, etc.

Comment: I find such info based on my experience in using the java reflection API , and then also quickly verify it by checking the codes that one of the `MethodInvocation` implementation is indeed get such value from the java `InvocationHandler` API , so its behaviour should be similar to the  `args` at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler.html#invoke-java.lang.Object-java.lang.reflect.Method-java.lang.Object:A-)

Comment: As said , you have to use `getClass()` to access an java object 's type information in order to know that if this object is in the type of something or not.

Comment: Yeah I just feel like the folks at Spring Security are making a big jump by not calling that out clearly in their documentation. `Object` could be anything, such as a `String`, or `SpringArgument<String>` or `SillyPuttyFizzybuzz`.